# Implementing an boolean statement in a switch

Tags: java

So I'm currently doing a first year university assignment and I'm a little stuck on one of the questions. It goes as such.
Modify the setType() and setPlan() methods to return a boolean true/false if the chosen type or plan was invalid. I.e if the type was "Bogus", ignore the type, and return a "false" to the call. Modify the Test class to add an "if" statement that will report a false call.

My current line of code for the method looks like this:

```
public void setType(String newType) {
    switch (newType) {
        case "Basic":
            mType = newType;
            break

        case "Enhanced":
            mType = newType;
            break

        default:
            break
}
```

My question is, how do I go about adding an if statement and does anything need to be changed to make the void method return a true/false value?

Comment: Smells like a case for an enum, though.

Comment: *My question is, how do I go about adding an if statement and does anything need to be changed to make the void method return a true/false value?* - This is just a rewording of exactly the same question the exam asked you, and the example you posted looks like the unmodified code. If you are unsure how to add `if` statements or change return types you really ought to read a language basics tutorial and consider whether or not you deserve a passing grade on the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public boolean setType(String newType) {
    switch (newType) {
    case "Basic":
    case "Enhanced":
        mType = newType;
        return true;
    default:
        return false;
    }
}
```

You don't actually need an extra `if` statement for doing this, and you can check two or more cases in a `switch` by  using a fallthrough (two or more consecutive `case`).

Answer (score 0):

You could define an array with all valid types in some globally accessible spot in your app:

```
public static final String[] VALID_TYPES = {"Basic","Enhanced"};
```

and then have a method that just iterates all those types and checks if a given value matches one of them:

```
public static boolean isValidType(String candidate){
  for(String validType : VALID_TYPES){
     if(validType.equals(candidate)){
        return true;
     }
  }
  return false;
}
```

The nice thing about this - in contrast to using switch statements - is that you can easily modifiy the list of valid types (add/change/remove types) without the need to touch your method that checks a given type for validity. So it's easy to maintain and less error-prone (in a switch, you might forget to add a case statement for each possible value, or you might forget to add a break statement somewhere, etc)

Comment: sorry, I didn't read your initial post properly. I gave another answer which contains the solution with the modified setType method

Answer (score 0):

Best practice would say this is "parameter checking", and it's cleaner too to *fail early*:

```
public boolean setType(String newType) {
    if (!newType.matches("Basic|Enhanced")) {
        return false;
    }
    type = newType; // or whatever you need to do 
    return true;
}
```

Options for testing also include:

```
if (!Arrays.asList("Basic", "Enhanced").contains(newType))
```

which also neatly handles `newType` being null without extra code.

But the best way to deal with this is to use an `enum`, which would not allow bad values in the first place.

Comment: about enum: That's right as far as "internal code" goes. But probably the given type is entered by the user. So if you use enums, you'd still need to validate the given string against the enum's, e.g. call YourEnum.valueOf(givenString) and see if it's null or not. So I think in this case it's easier to just stick with strings

Comment: Come on, man, this is just a copy + pasted assignment question and [you should know better](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253793/616460).

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are good.  Here's my take. The ternary operator, `?` and `:` expression,  is logically an "if then else".

```
public boolean setType(String newType) {
    boolean result = (newType.equals("Basic") || newType.equals("Enhanced"));
    mType = result ? newType : mType; 
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Your return type should be boolean. ;)

Comment: possible. But I'd recommend to exchange the order of the equals calls, i.e. "Basic".equals(newType) instead of newType.equals("Basic"), to avoid possible NullPointerExceptions

Answer (score 0):

```
public class YourClass{

   private String mType;

   private static final List<String> VALID_TYPES = Arrays.asList("Basic","Enhanced");

   public boolean setType(String newType){
      if(!VALID_TYPES.contains(newType)){
         return false;
      }
      mType = newType;
      return true;
   }
}
```

And similar for the setPlan method, just define another list of VALID_PLANS.

And about your test class:

```
if(!yourClassObject.setType("Some Invalid Type")){
   System.err.println("Invalid type!");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

adding a boolean property of class,like this：

```
public class Test
{
    private boolean flag;
}
```